# XOR of two Strings not working when size of strings is big

Tags: java, string, byte, xor

I am trying to XOR two strings and then again XOR the output with one string to get the other string. Sometimes it is working as expected but sometimes it gives some unexpected result.

```
    private static byte[] xorData(byte[] data1, byte[] data2) throws    UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String l1s=new String(data1);
    String l2s=new String(data2);
    int l1=data1.length;
    int l2=data2.length;
    if(l1>l2)
    {
        while(l1s.length()!=l2s.length()){
            l2s=l2s+"0";
        }
    }
    if(l1<l2)
    {
        while(l1s.length()!=l2s.length()){
            l1s=l1s+"0";
        }
    }
    data1=l1s.getBytes();
    data2=l2s.getBytes();
    System.out.println("data1 len "+data1.length);
    System.out.println("data2 length "+data2.length);
    byte[] result=new byte[data1.length];
    for(int i=0;i<data1.length;i++){
            result[i]=(byte)(data1[i] ^ data2[i%data2.length]);
        }

    System.out.println("*********final resulttttttt*******************  "+new String(result,"UTF-8"));
    return result;
}
```

Similar way I will perform XOR with the output of above method and first string to get the second string. Note: To this method I am passing bytes array instead of passing String

Comment: Why would you convert binary data into strings to start with? You're converting it to strings and then back again... this is very odd code.

Comment: bytes are not characters, and vice-versa.

Comment: Can you give us some context? What are you trying to achieve? What are your expected results?

Comment: I am trying to send one file from client to server. At client side, I have to read one file, then split it into three parts. I have to perform XOR between the content of first and second file and then perform XOR between the content of second and third file. I will send second file content  and the result of both the XOR operations to server. At server side, I will XOR content of second file (which is plaintext) with both the XOR outputs to get back original first and third file content. I hope I am able to explain you what I am trying to implement.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor you're using to build your strings is the [`byte[]` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-) for the `String` type, which I think is doing something other than what you're expecting. That function works by trying to decode the raw bytes as some encoding of Unicode code points rather than as a sequence of individual `char` values. For example, if your platform is planning on using UTF-8 encodings, it might interpret a series of bytes as an encoding of a single character rather than as multiple individual bytes. As a result, converting to and from `String` using this constructor will likely mess up your data.

If you want to XOR together all the bytes into a final array, don't go through a `String` intermediary. Instead, just directly XOR the bytes in the arrays.

It seems like you were primarily using the `String` type so that you could pad the input arrays to get them up to the same size. If that's the case, rather than routing through `String`s, try something like this:

```
byte[] result = new Byte[Math.max(data1.length, data2.length)];
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    byte first  = (i < data1.length? data1[i] : (byte)0);
    byte second = (i < data2.length? data2[i] : (byte)0);
    result[i] = (byte)(first ^ second);
}
```